# FFmpeg error while adding watermark: Not overwriting - exiting

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, flutter-video-player, mobile-ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg

I'm implementing a video editing feature on my Flutter App using the [Flutter-FFmpeg package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg), [Adding watermarks on video] specifically, while executing the code I got this error:

```
E/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): Not overwriting - exiting
D/flutter-ffmpeg( 5731): FFmpeg exited with rc: 1
```

***Most importantly, the output file cannot be played by the VideoPlayer. And it just LOADS FOREVER, the `VideoController` Widget shows that the player is buffering. I've tested My VideoPlayer widget, and it works very well on the videos that were not processed.***

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    await FlutterFFmpeg().execute(
        '-i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=5:5 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4'
    );
```

A full log of the executing process in case it helps:

```
D/flutter-ffmpeg( 5731): Running FFmpeg with arguments: [-i, /data/user/0/com.raheyo.cheese/cache/REC5995709221575585296.mp4, -i, /data/user/0/com.raheyo.cheese/cache/e0baa6a8-4d4c-407a-a73e-be4dcf4d08fd.mp4, -filter_complex, [0:v][1:v]overlay=5:5, -c:a, copy, -movflags, +faststart, /data/user/0/com.raheyo.cheese/cache/e0baa6a8-4d4c-407a-a73e-be4dcf4d08fd.mp4].
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): Loading mobile-ffmpeg.
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): Loaded mobile-ffmpeg-full-arm64-v8a-4.4-20200725.
D/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): Callback thread started.
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/com.raheyo.cheese/cache/REC5995709221575585296.mp4':
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     major_brand     :
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): mp42
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     minor_version   :
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 0
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     compatible_brands:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): isommp42
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     creation_time   :
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 2021-08-06T19:50:53.000000Z
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     com.android.version:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 9
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   Duration:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 00:00:01.69
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): , start:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 0.000000
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): , bitrate:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 12834 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     Stream #0:0
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): (eng)
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m), 1920x1080, 12728 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): , SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): ,
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 20.09 fps,
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 30 tbr,
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 90k tbn,
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 180k tbc
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):  (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):       rotate          :
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 90
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):       creation_time   :
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 2021-08-06T19:50:53.000000Z
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):       handler_name    :
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): VideoHandle
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     Side data:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     Stream #0:1
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): (eng)
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):  (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):       creation_time   :
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): 2021-08-06T19:50:53.000000Z
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):       handler_name    :
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): SoundHandle
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): Input #1, png_pipe, from '/data/user/0/com.raheyo.cheese/cache/e0baa6a8-4d4c-407a-a73e-be4dcf4d08fd.mp4':
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):   Duration:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): N/A
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): , bitrate:
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): N/A
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731):     Stream #1:0
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): : Video: png, rgba(pc), 393x822
I/mobile-ffmpeg( 5731): ,
```

Comment: Were you able to get this to work in Flutter? Even copying your FFmpeg command, I can still not even get the function to overwrite the original video file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when target output file already exists. Make sure it is not the same file as the input. Then add `-y` to force overwrite output in case it already exists.

Comment: Thanks. After added `-y`, the console appears this `E/mobile-ffmpeg(25665): Output /data/user/0/com.raheyo.cheese/cache/9ac4f73952.mp4 same as Input #1 - exiting
W/mobile-ffmpeg(25665): FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place.
I/ExoPlayerImpl(25665): Init 9f76268 [ExoPlayerLib/2.13.1] [violet, Redmi Note 7 Pro, Xiaomi, 28]
D/AudioManager(25665): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25665): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(25665):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error`. And the player still couldn't play, it just loads forever.

Comment: As it says, `FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place.`. The output file cannot be the same as an input file.